# HTML Form Target not working in Chrome 20+

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, popup

Does anyone know how to set the target of a HTML FORM to a newly created pop-up window in Chrome 20+. The below code works in every browser, even worked in previous versions of Chrome, except Chrome 20+:

```
var f = document.getElementByID("my_form");
window.open('','popup_win','scrollbars=yes,menubar=no,height=500,width='+(screen.width>1100?1100:screen.width)+',resizable=yes,toolbar=no,status=no,location=0');
f.target = this.win;
f.submit();
```

This code creates a new window, but it doesn't contain the resulting form submission page content.

We need to use "window.open" so we can best set the size of the window for our application to be displayed.

After doing some research it appears that it has to do with the Chrome Popup blocker. ([New Window Links Not Working with Chrome](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?711054-link-open-new-window-not-working-in-Chrome-browser)). After I added the site to the "Always allow" list in Chrome the content displayed.

Anyone know how to do this type of thing without any user interaction?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Use a lightbox instead of a pop up window.

Comment: @RickCalder thanks for the suggestion but that really isn't an option. This JS is basically for an API snippet and the API integrators don't want the window that we create to interfere with the page its initiated from. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: The explanation does, the requirement not so much to be honest. I think you may have to resort to the "This page uses pop ups, you may have to disable any pop up blockers you have for it to function correctly" style message on the page. There is no way I know of to block the pop up blocker... if there were it wouldn't be of much use to be honest.

Comment: @RickCalder Yeah, I'm not asking for a way to "disable" the popup blocker per say. I am asking if there is another technique that could be used so the pop-up blocker doesn't block the popup. :) I was thinking exactly that about the message, but I wanted to look at all the options to see if there is in-fact another technique. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the cause of Chromes pop-up blocking settings, once added to allow sites it displayed correctly.

Added a message above the button for chrome users, if a blank window add our site to your allow popup sites.